# How can we setup more than 5 applications at one place using PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps-canvas, matlab-app-designer, powerapps-modeldriven

I want to design more than 5 mobile Applications, but it took lots of time. So I want to set up all applications at one place, Is PowerApps suitable for it?

Answer (score 0):

In PowerApps you can create multiple Apps, but each app is individual.

You can have in each App multiple pages/screens. You can show hide screens/pages based on what you want to show to whom.

Answer (score 0):

I wish we could write code in simple JSON format, but the WYSIWG low-code format necessitates applying little bits of code to all sorts of places in the app. See ["Where's the Code?"](https://powerapps.rocks/wheres-the-code/).

You could *technically* create all common sections of the apps in a [Component Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/component-library) then create each PowerApp separately using the components, customizing per the app specs as needed. Then package the apps as a [Solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/solutions-overview) so they reside under version control, etc.

**But at this point...its easier for me to:**

0. Create a DEV/PROD Env's (if you don't have them already)
1. Create a few simple components (header, footer, etc.)
2. Use these components to "outline" the app
3. Customize each app with data sources, collections, Galleries, etc.
4. Test
5. Then export from DEV env, import to PROD env
6. Make simple (yet CRITICAL!) config changes
7. Rinse and repeat

**Disclaimer:**

- 4yr PowerApps dev
- Canvas Apps only
- DataVerse averse